# How to create in-memory file object

Tags: python, io

I want to make a in-memory file to use in pygame mixer. I mean something like  http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load which says load() method supports file object.

```
import requests
from pygame import mixer

r = requests.get("http://example.com/some_small_file.mp3")
in_memory_file = file(r.content) # something like this
mixer.music.init()
mixer.music.load(in_memory_file)
mixer.music.play()
```

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You are probably looking for `BytesIO` or `StringIO` classes from Python `io` package, both available in [python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/io.html) and [python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html). They provide a file-like interface you can use in your code the exact same way you interact with a real file.

`StringIO` is used to store textual data:

```
import io

f = io.StringIO("some initial text data")
```

`BytesIO` must be used for binary data:

```
import io

f = io.BytesIO(b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01")
```

To store MP3 file data, you will probably need the `BytesIO` class. To initialize it from a GET request to a server, proceed like this:

```
import requests
from pygame import mixer
import io

r = requests.get("http://example.com/somesmallmp3file.mp3")
inmemoryfile = io.BytesIO(r.content)

mixer.music.init()
mixer.music.load(inmemoryfile)
mixer.music.play()

# This will free the memmory from any data
inmemoryfile.close()
```

Additional note: as both classes inherit from [IOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase), they can be used as context manager with the `with` statement, so you don't need to manually call the `close()` method anymore:

```
import requests
from pygame import mixer
import io

r = requests.get("http://example.com/somesmallmp3file.mp3")

with io.BytesIO(r.content) as inmemoryfile:
    mixer.music.init()
    mixer.music.load(inmemoryfile)
    mixer.music.play()
```