# How do I upload an .xlsx file to an FTP without creating a local file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, openpyxl, ftplib

I am writing a script to pull xml files from an FTP, turn them into an .xlsx file, and re-upload to a different directory on the same FTP. I want to create the .xlsx file within my script instead of copying the xml data into a template and uploading my local file.

I tried creating a filename for the .xlsx doc, but i realize that i need to save it before i can upload to the FTP. My question is, would it be better to create a temporary folder on the server the script is being run and empty the folder out afterwards? or is there a way to upload the doc without saving it anywhere (preferred)? I will be running the script on a windows server

```py
ftps.cwd(ftpExcelDir)
wbFilename = str(orderID + '.xlsx')
savedFile = saving the file somwhere    # this is the part im having trouble with
ftps.storline('STOR ' + wbFilename, savedFile)
```

With the following code, i can get the .xlsx files to save to the FTP, but i recieve an invalid extension/corrupt file error from Excel:

```py
ftps.cwd(ftpExcelDir)
wbFilename = str(orderID + '.xlsx')
inMemoryWB = io.BytesIO()
wb.save(inMemoryWB)
ftps.storbinary('STOR ' + wbFilename, inMemoryWB)
```

Comment: The preferred approach here will depend on OS.  For example, on linux you can likely create a temporary file in `/dev/shm`, which will be easy to do and act like a normal file, but will actually only exist in memory.

Comment: @JamesK - That would be a great fix, but i am running Windows unfortunatley

Comment: openpyxl requires file objects and you can't stream XLSX anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The ftp functions take file objects... but those don't strictly speaking need to be files.  Python has `BytesIO` and `StringIO` objects which act like files, but are backed by memory.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672691/8833934