# How do I async pickle a lot of files with aiofiles?

Tags: python, async-await, dill, python-aiofiles

I have a list I'd like to write out, `data`, one file for each item like so:

```
for i,chunk in enumerate(data):
    fname = ROOT / f'{i}.in'
    with open(fname, "wb") as fout:
        dill.dump(chunk, fout)
```

Since the data list can be quite long and I'm writing to a network storage location, I'm spending a lot of time waiting for the iteration in NFS back and forth, and I'd like to do this asynchronously if possible.

I have something that basically looks like this now:

```
import dill
import asyncio
import aiofiles
from pathlib import Path

ROOT = Path("/tmp/")

data = [str(i) for i in range(500)]

def serialize(data):
  """
  Write my data out in serial
  """
  for i,chunk in enumerate(data):
    fname = ROOT / f'{i}.in'
    print(fname)
    with open(fname, "wb") as fout:
        dill.dump(chunk, fout)

def aserialize(data):
  """
  Same as above, but writes my data out asynchronously
  """
  fnames = [ROOT / f'{i}.in' for i in range(len(data))]
  chunks = data
  async def write_file(i):
    fname = fnames[i]
    chunk = chunks[i]
    print(fname)
    async with aiofiles.open(fname, "wb") as fout:
        print(f"written: {i}")
        dill.dump(chunk, fout)
        await fout.flush()
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[write_file(i) for i in range(len(data))]))
```

Now, when I test the writes, this looks fast enough to be worthwhile on my NFS:

```
# test 1
start = datetime.utcnow()
serialize(data)
end = datetime.utcnow()
print(end - start)
# >>> 0:02:04.204681

# test 3
start = datetime.utcnow()
aserialize(data)
end = datetime.utcnow()
print(end - start)
# >>> 0:00:27.048893
# faster is better.
```

But when I actually /de/-serialize the data I wrote, I see that maybe it was fast because it wasn't writing anything:

```
def deserialize(dat):
  tmp = []
  for i in range(len(dat)):
    fname = ROOT / f'{i}.in'
    with open(fname, "rb") as fin:
      fo = dill.load(fin)
    tmp.append(fo)
  return tmp

serialize(data)
d2 = deserialize(data)
d2 == data
# True
```

Good, whereas:

```
aserialize(data)
d3 = deserialize(data)
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in deserialize
  File "...python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 305, in load
    obj = pik.load()
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

That is, the asynchronously written files are empty.  No wonder it was so fast.

How can I dill/pickle my list into files asynchronously and get them to actually write?   I assume I need to await the dill.dump somehow? I thought the fout.flush would handle that, but seems not.

Comment: In aiofiles `write` method is a coroutine. Which means `f.write()` has to be awaited. dill library don't know about it and thinks the `fin` you passed is a regular file. You should have got "RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited". @sanyash 's answer should get it working. But not sure if it will be faster

Answer (score 1):

I changed the line `dill.dump(chunk, fout)` to `await fout.write(dill.dumps(chunk))` and got the data written to the files and deserialized correctly. Seems like `dill.dump` works only with regular synchronous files calling `file.write` method without `await` keyword.

Comment: Are these equivalent?  I'm looking at: https://dill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dill.html#dill._dill.dumps and it's not clear to me that `f.write(dill.dumps(x)) == dill.dump(x, f)`

Comment: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/_dill.py#L253-L266

Comment: @Mittenchops as you see, `dumps` uses `dump` to write data to `StringIO` object, which acts like in-memory file (https://stackoverflow.com/q/44672524/9609843). Thus its content is supposed to be equal to those written to a regular file.