# Passing in a string instead of a file_location into a function

Tags: python

I am using a library that has a function like the below, where it expects a file location. The thing is, I store the content of this file in AWS  so I can just use AWS api to securely return values I have stored in that resource as a string. How can I transform this string value to be able to pass in a function that is looking for file path - without actually just writing the string values to the local directory as .txt for json file?  (I know I can convert the string to a json object but not certain as to how this solves the fact this function is looking for a path) function below:

```
file_location = 'String values I get returned when I return it from its safe and secure location'

password = credential_function.from_kefile_name(file_location)
```

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672524/how-to-create-in-memory-file-object

Comment: @PM77-1 - thank you, when using the io.stringIO (similar to what is referenced above) I am getting TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.StringIO

Comment: @PM77-1

I have 

variable = 'string'
output = io.StringIO()
output.write(variable)
FILE_LOCATION = output.seek(0)

And it is not working?