# Create In Memory File Object to be passed into a function

Tags: python, io

I am trying to pass in a file in-memory . So I am referencing this post here to create in-memory file object: [How to create in-memory file object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672524/how-to-create-in-memory-file-object)

I created the code below, but now when I pass in my function.

```
fil_location = io.StringIO()

fil_location.write('test')



password = credential_function.from_keyfile_name(fil_location)
```

I get this error:

```
  with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.StringIO
```

Comment: `from_kefile_name()` requires the argument to be a filename, not a file object.

Comment: Check the documentation to see if there's a method that takes a file object instead of name. In-memory file objects don't have names.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for that - it does not. Is there way to make a name for a inmemory file object?

Comment: No, there isn't. Filenames are managed by the kernel, it doesn't know anything about in-memory objects.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation of the module you're using?

Comment: @Barmar https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html - this is the docs I am using

Comment: I mean the module with `credential_function.from_kefile_name`

Comment: So I can see if it provides a method that takes an open file instead of a filename.

Comment: @Barmar https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html

Comment: There's no `from_keyfile_name()` method. Did you mean `from_json_keyfile_name()`? But you're not writing JSON to `fil_location`

Comment: And if you have the JSON in memory, you don't need to use the file object, you can just use `from_json()`.