# How to write to a string instead of a file wth PyYaml

Tags: python, string, yaml, pyyaml

I can write to a file using `yaml.dump` but how do I write to a string?

Comment: Assuming it's doing something similar to the built-in `json` package, `.dumps`? If that doesn't work I'd use an in-memory "file": https://stackoverflow.com/q/44672524/3001761.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Its an overloaded function. If you don't pass the file parameter, it will output to a string.