# How to test a function that loads a pickle file without actual IO operations

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pickle

I have written a function that loads a pickled list of dictionaries and optionally filters the result:

```py
def load_pickled_list(path_to_file, filter_key=None):
    with open(path_to_file, "rb") as file:
        loaded_list = pickle.load(file)

    if filter_key is not None:
        loaded_list = [entry for entry in loaded_list if loaded_list[filter_key] == filter_key]

    return loaded_list
```

How do I test this with pytest by providing two different lists of dictionaries in code? Especially, how do I implement a test double of pickle? I do not want to provide a file such as `test_list.pkl` so that the test would have to perform real disk IO operations.

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672524/how-to-create-in-memory-file-object

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sequence of bytes in mind, you can hard-code it directly into your program using [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO). The [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) in the module docs may be what you need, or at least provide a good starting point:

```
f = io.BytesIO(b"your pickle file here ")
loaded_list = pickle.load(f)
```

Better than hard-coding the data, have some part of your setup or a fixture generate it:

```
# make some objects
data = ...
f = io.BytesIO()
pickle.dump(data, f)
f.seek(0)

# now load `f`
```

You could also avoid the file interface entirely by using [`dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps)/[`loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads) to work with `bytes` directly instead of doing I/O with [`dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump)/[`load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load).

Comment: Thank you. But now I can't pass `f` into a call of `load_pickled_list` within my test because the function expects a string and not a BytesIO object.

Comment: @LuGeNat. That's because your function can't handle file objects. I would recommend that you allow it to do that.

Comment: @LuGeNat. I'm not aware of any way to pass in an in-memory file without passing either bytes or file-like objects. The only other thing I can think of is adding a prefix to your data to let your function know that it's not really a string it's dealing with: